# How do I build a LR state machine parser?

Tags: state-machine, parser-generator

I'm wanting to play around with creating an LR parser generators. Does anyone know of a good (free) resource describing how to create a state machine table from a grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a free resource, consider the Python source code for [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) - a full implementation of Lex and Yacc in Python.

I would recommend a book, however, and you can hardly do better than get [The Dragon Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201100886).

Comment: I really should just break down and buy a copy (and looking at the used prices I might just do that) but I'm often to stingy. Besides, it's sort of a sacrilege to spend money on "totally useless but cool code hacks"

Comment: Absolutely not "totally useless". Reading the dragon book can teach you a lot about programming. Armed with a good understanding of LR parsers you'll be better able to grasp new languages and design others, such as DSLs for specific tasks.

Comment: I've already written a parser generator (recursive descent) and played with languages on a number of projects. The "totally useless" part is that fact that the implementation language is going to be MySQL!

Answer (score 1):

The best resource I have come across is:

[Parsing Techniques - A Practical Guide](http://www.cs.vu.nl/~dick/PTAPG.html)

Comment: Looks like it's out of print :(. If I see a copy I'll take a look.

Comment: There's a first edition available as a PDF from that website. It doesn't get close to the Dragon, though.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is the standard compiler text by Aho/Ullman/Ravi, [Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201100886)

It has complete chapters on parsing. It isn't free, but it is worth every last penny, and if you are going to build parsers or other compiler-like tools, you are simply crazy if you don't have this book.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you find Grammatica useful. It's a free Parser generator for .NET. I have some experience with it and it was good. You can try it and study its code.
http://grammatica.percederberg.net/

Comment: Gotta love when people downvote an answer without stating their issue with it... I'd appreciate the feedback